# Joining tables, with counts, and dates

Tags: mysql

I'm wanting to join two tables and retrieve a count from one based on a date.

I have a table **access_points**:

```
access_points_id, access_points_name
```

and another table **access_points_launched**:

```
access_points_launched_id, access_points_name, launched_date
```

I want to return all the access_points with a count of how many entries it has in access_points_launched for the current date:

```
Access Point, Launched Count, Date
WIFI_point, 2, 05/01/2015
FREE_INTERNET, 0, 05/01/2015
SPRINT_INTERNET, 5, 05/01/2015
```

I don't want the count to include any other dates.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get aggregated count in a subquery and can do `left join` with access_points table to get the desired result.

```
select a.access_points_name, aggr.totalCount , curdate()
from access_points a
left join ( select access_points_name, count(*) as totalCount
            from access_points_launched
            where date(launched_date) = curdate() 
            group by access_points_name
          ) aggr
on aggr.access_points_name =  a.access_points_name
```